# linq to sql throwing an exception row not found or changed

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I am linq to sql and i am getting the error of row not found or changed.

I am updating my table with the help of linq query then sometime it is showing this error.
I am unable to figure out this problem because sometimes it's working or sometime not.

But i am not getting any permanent solution to fix this problem.

```
twtmob_campainincomedetails_tb incomedetails = dataContext.twtmob_campainincomedetails_tbs.Single(twtincome => twtincome.incomeid == tempincomes);
                decimal temppayout = decimal.Parse(lblpertweet.Text);
                decimal temptotal = temppayout + tempmoneyearned;
                incomedetails.moneyearned = Convert.ToString(temptotal);
                incomedetails.tweet = temptweet + 1;
                incomedetails.bonus = lblbonus.Text;
                incomedetails.budurl = tempbudurl;
                dataContext.SubmitChanges();

 twtmob_user_tb twtuserdetails = dataContext.twtmob_user_tbs.Single(twtdetail => twtdetail.twtmobuserid == tempUserId);
        {
            float temppayout = float.Parse(lblpertweet.Text);
            float tempoutstandingtotal = temppayout+tempoutstanding;
            twtuserdetails.outstandingbalances = tempoutstandingtotal;
            dataContext.SubmitChanges();
        }
```

Comment: Could you give more information?  Maybe the linq query your using and some information about the table or tables you are accessing?

Comment: thanks for your reply

I have User table there lot of information in the table related to user.
And primary key is Userid when i am updating other field on the basis of primary key then some time its showing the error and working fine.

I am adding the code whatever i am using.

Answer (score 3):

This is a concurrency conflict exception error message.

You can avoid it by setting to none the UpdateCheck property of all your Entity's properties.  But this is equivalent to Last-In-Wins, which you may not want.

Or you can use a timestamp on the DB to check for this concurrency, it will become a property on your object and it will be used during an update to find the record (in addition to the Primary Key).  If the record is not found to perform an update, a ChangeConflictExcpetion is thrown.  Remember to store it somewhere if you work in disonnected mode, like in ASP.NET.

You have to take some time to get your head around that concept...

[How to: Manage Change Conflicts (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399389.aspx)